# Wordpress GCM to iOS

Tags: ios, wordpress, google-cloud-messaging

I have iOS app that use GCM. The GCM is plugin into Wordpress, so when push notification it didn't play sound and only able to display the notification banner when it foreground. when app inactive or background it nothing to pop up. Besides that, in phone notification list it didn't display on there too. May i know anyone have solution for all these situation before?